# Java compiler overwriting and mangling source file

Tags: java, javac, annotation-processing

I have a single, short Java file with a single `main` method. It imports from a third-party library that I'll call `thirdpartylib`. I run

```
javac -classpath "../thirdpartylib/lib/*" MyClass.java
```

at the command line. I get the following command-line output:

```
warning: Supported source version 'RELEASE_6' from annotation processor 'org.mangosdk.spi.processor.SpiProcessor' less than -source '1.8'
MyClass.java:14: error: unreported exception Exception; must be caught or declared to be thrown
d.put(125,   new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(0, 1, 2)));
                         ^
  exception thrown from implicit call to close() on resource variable 'facade'
MyClass.java:39: error: unreported exception Exception; must be caught or declared to be thrown
2 errors
1 warning
```

Then when I open `MyClass.java` back up in my editor to investigate the reported errors, my Java file has been completely rewritten! (My editor's undo history saved me.) The top of the file reads

```
# Generated by org.mangosdk.spi.processor.SpiProcessor (0.2.4)
# Mon, 18 Jul 2016 10:10:47 -0500
```

and the rest of my code looks like it was sorted row-wise in alphabetical order -- not valid Java syntax to say the least. Googling around got me to an apparently [defunct](https://code.google.com/archive/p/spi/) package called [SPI](https://github.com/mykelalvis/spi). I have not installed it on my computer, except perhaps if `thirdpartylib` is using it, but that doesn't explain why it's destroying my source code.

How can I compile my program if the compiler keeps deleting my source code?

Comment: I'm inclined to think that you have good evidence that the annotation processor in question is indeed installed on your system.  It looks like it is incompatible with with Java 8, so find it and get rid of it.

Comment: Until then, I *speculate* that the annotation processor assumes that your Java sources are in a different directory than the working directory, and that it is not intentionally overwriting them.  If you put your classes in a package, arrange sources accordingly, and run the compiler from the source root then *maybe* you will avoid overwriting your sources, but you probably still will not get a successful build.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the classpath contains an annotation processor. Annotation processors should usually only generate new resources and not modify existing ones, but they do have the ability to change any files.

You can try to use the compiler option `-proc:none` to disable all annotation processing.

```
javac -proc:none -classpath "../thirdpartylib/lib/*" MyClass.java
```

Comment: Adding `-proc:none` did the trick. After fixing the "unreported exception" mentioned in the OP (it was unrelated to the annotation processor), the whole thing compiled and ran correctly. Thanks!